# Github CD Pipelines crashes on production build with ES modules as config

Tags: github, webpack, babeljs, github-pages, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my github pages using CD.

My CI seems to properly work with es modules as my webpack config(https://github.com/crrmacarse/crrmacarse.github.io/actions/runs/31859113) but when i try to do it on CD it crashes with this error:

[image]

Here is my yml config:

```
name: Release

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - source

env:
  NODE_ENV: production
  PUBLIC_URL: http://crrmacarse.github.io/
  GA_TRACKING_CODE: ${{ secrets.GA_TRACKING_CODE }}
  FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2.0.0

    - name: Use node 12
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
          node-version: 12
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org

    - name: install
      run: npm install
    - name: build
      run: npm run prod
    # https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-node.html#not-meant-for-production-use
    # - name: build sitemap
    #   run: npm run sitemap
    - name: copy
      run: npm run copy

    - name: Build and Deploy
      uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@releases/v3
      with:
        ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
        BRANCH: master
        FOLDER: dist
```

Iirc, I used babel-preset to achieve this ES module exports. Where did it went wrong?

Here is the code in question

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-dynamic-require, global-require
export default (env) => require(`./compiler/${env}.js`);
```

https://github.com/crrmacarse/crrmacarse.github.io/blob/source/webpack.config.babel.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it with this commit:

https://github.com/crrmacarse/crrmacarse.github.io/commit/b871b68e8d76ee95d9f538ec5ff2992e472da2bd#diff-56c30d9224897b08c28075052d4595c5

It was probably either the removal of NODE_ENV or FIREBASE_TOKEN(Which doesn't exist)